# Adding items to an array using a foreach loop in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, foreach

I am trying to do a homework assignment that requires using a foreach loop to add items to an array. I did it using a for loop but cannot figure it out with a foreach loop.

Here is what I need, just in a foreach loop instead.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("\tPlease enter a score for {0} <0 to 100>: ",  studentName[i]);
            studentScore[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            counter = i + 1;
            accumulator += studentScore[i];
        }
```

Sorry if this has been asked but I could not find an answer that helped me.

Comment: `foreach` is used with an array or list or anything of that sort.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do, because you can't change the iteration variable while you are iterating (so @mikeTheLair suggestion won't work if you are using it to input scores).

Comment: Perhaps reading the book on how a `foreach` keyword works. You could also google the MSDN for it to see some examples.

Comment: @Matt you're right, slipped my mind. I'm actually not sure how you would go about this then.

Comment: you cant do this with foreach loop. is this really homework? foreach loop is for a simple iterations and also you cant change the elements on iterating array.

Comment: I *guess* you could define `int[] studentScore = new int[5];` and then do something like `foreach(var i in Enumerable.Range(0,5))`, technically you are using a `foreach` loop, but it would be utterly pointless. Perhaps you meant to loop over `studentName`? That collection, I assume, is already populated?

Comment: Perhaps if you have an array of `Student`, instead of two arrays?

Comment: @crashmstr: Without a doubt, an array of objects with properties is much better than two parallel arrays that you have to try to keep in sync, but I'm guessing that's beyond what the homework is looking for.

Comment: @MattBurland hard to tell, since we don't know what the full assignment entails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop through the names array using a foreach loop and read the scores as shown below

```
foreach(string name in studentName)
{
    Console.Write("\tPlease enter a score for {0} <0 to 100>: ", name);
    studentScore[counter] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());                
    accumulator += studentScore[counter];
    counter++;
}

Console.WriteLine(accumulator);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked perfectly. I had tried something nearly like this but messed it up a bit.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a class like:

```
class Student
{
    public string Name {get; set; }
    public int Score {get; set; }
}
```

and a `foreach` like:

```
var counter = 0;

foreach (student in studentsArray)
{
    Console.Write("\tPlease enter a score for {0} <0 to 100>: ",  student.Name);
    student.Score = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    counter++;
    accumulator += student.Score;
}
```

Comment: @juharr I assumed its just a part of some code there might be used after this code. But for this code, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you meant something like this:

```
var studentScores = new List<int>();
foreach (var student in studentName)   // note: collections really should be named plural
{
    Console.Write("\tPlease enter a score for {0} <0 to 100>: ",  student);
    studentScores.Add(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));
    accumulator += studentScores.Last();
}
```

If you must use an array, then something like this:

```
var studentScores = new int[studentName.Length];    // Do not hardcode the lengths
var idx = 0;
foreach (var student in studentName)
{
    Console.Write("\tPlease enter a score for {0} <0 to 100>: ",  student);
    studentScores[idx] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    accumulator += studentScores[idx++];
}
```

Comment: Question says "array", so unless the OP is not using the correct terms, this would not be it.

Comment: Somehow I suspect that OP's class has not covered collection classes yet.

Comment: @crashmstr: Changing it to an array is trivial. Using a list is better anyway (no need to track indexes). Using a list of objects (instead of two parallel collections) would be the best solution.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar: I don't see that as remotely relevant. It's a chance to learn something and questions and answers don't exist solely for the benefit of the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Using spans, you are able to get reference vars with the enumerator provided like this: `foreach (ref var el in span) {...}`. Because they are refs, you are able to modify the values in the array.

Not recommended since foreach loops in pretty much any language generally have zero intent for modifications. Enumerators and iterators in some languages, including C#, don't allow modifications to collections like using `Add` or `Remove` methods.